# Python 3.3 Tkinter: Is there any way to move widgets to the centre of the screen using .grid geometry?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, geometry

Is there any way to move widgets to the centre of the screen using .grid geometry in Python 3.3's tkinter? Even when changing the rows and coloumns everything is at the top left. (New to Python, stackoverflow and coding in general).
Thank you

Comment: When you say "move widgets to the centre of the screen" do you mean the center of the physical display, or centered in their respective parent windows?

Answer (score 0):

Within the tkinter module, you can use the .grid method to be able to centre your widgets on the screen:

```
Label(master, text="First")
Label.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label2(master, text="Second")
Label2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

However I would use the .place function; this will allow you to write the coordinates where you want the widgets to be.

```
Label(master, text="First")
Label..place(x=20, y=30)

Label2(master, text="Second")
Label2..place(x=20, y=50)
```

This .place method is much easier to be able to maintain, when moving widgets around.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to using the grid geometry manager, you can also try out [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm).
Pack automatically places widgets in the center of the window, and places new widgets below the first one if you continue to 'pack' them without specifying any particular position.

If you want to specify where a widget goes, you can also do so in the .pack() call, but you're limited in options.

**Here's an example:**

```
Mywidget.pack(side=TOP)
```

[image: When specifying side = TOP]

```
Mywidget.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

[image]

side = allows you ***only a few options*** though, such as *TOP*, *BOTTOM*, *LEFT*, and *RIGHT*

I don't know if this is too limiting for you, but if you're new to Python, pack is somewhat simpler than grid to use in my opinion. Although you may well need grid for more sophisticated placements of widgets, ect.

Comment: your comment about pack placing things in the middle is untrue. Your own examples show that it's going to put it at the top or the bottom (or one of the sides).

Comment: I see why you think that, but it places them in the center (middle) of the window. They may be at the top, or the bottom, but they are still in the center of the 'row' they are in. If you understand what I mean. They aren't placed at the dead middle of the window, but they are in the center.. ahh column? So to speak? It's difficult to articulate.

Answer (score 0):

Grid (as well as place and pack) can be used to position widgets in the center of their parent. If you're asking about the center of the physical screen, the best you can do is use `wm_geometry` to move the window to the physical center.

If you really want to use grid, and you want to place a single widget in the center of its parent, place it in row 1, column 1, and give the surrounding rows and columns a weight of 1 (one). This will guarantee that the edges will grow and shrink as the window resizes.

Most likely what is happening is that you're trying to put a widget in some random grid cell, but the widget still shows up in the corner. This is because the other cells don't exist -- rows and columns by default have zero width and height, so even if you put something at row 10,000, if there is nothing in the other 9,999 rows, row 10,000 will appear at the top. Adding to the confusion is the fact that by default, rows and columns don't grow as the window grows.

This is really only a problem when experimenting. In practice, you'll typically have widgets in all your rows and columns so these rows and columns won't have zero width.

Here's a working example. Notice that as you resize the window that the label stays in the middle. The thing that makes this work is that I've given a weight to all rows and columns except the center one, so they take up all the extra space which leaves the sole widget in the center.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="I am centered!")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```